# Javascript mobileMenuToggle Function need to be load with site

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick

I am new to stackoverflow.com, looking for a bit help of a code hope you can help me out.

Here is website http://newwebdemo.com/builf/

If you open this website in mobile or resize your windows to smaller, you will see a mobileMenuToggle will appear instead of normal desktop menu of website!

What i want is currently the menu slidedown when i click on it and close once i click on it again, i need it to be default opened with website is load, and i can close it when i click on it,

Here is the code if this section, your help will solve my problem

```
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {

    $('#header-wrapper').addClass('is_tablet');

    $('#header-inner .mobile-nav').css('display','block');

    $('#header-inner ul.navigation, #header-inner ul.mobile-navigation').css('display','none');

    $('#header-inner .mobileMenuToggle').css('display','block');

    $('.menu').not('.mobile-nav .menu').css({display:'none'});

}

$('.mobileMenuToggle a').on('click', function() {

    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {

        $('ul.mobile-navigation').slideUp(400,'easeInOutQuint');

        $(this).removeClass('open');

    } else {

        $('ul.mobile-navigation').slideDown(400,'easeInOutQuint');

        $(this).addClass('open');

    }

    return false;

});
```

What it is doing currenty is adding class name "open" to

```
<div class="mobileMenuToggle"><a href=""></a></div>
```

when you click it change in code like that and menu slidedown and open

```
<div class="mobileMenuToggle"><a href="" class="open"></a></div>
```

you can see once i click on menu while i am on mobile or in smaller size of browser, it open menu on click, i want it to be default opened with website!

Can please someone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a trigger after attaching the click event, something like:

```
    if(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {

    $('#header-wrapper').addClass('is_tablet');

    $('#header-inner .mobile-nav').css('display','block');

    $('#header-inner ul.navigation, #header-inner ul.mobile-navigation').css('display','none');

    $('#header-inner .mobileMenuToggle').css('display','block');

    $('.menu').not('.mobile-nav .menu').css({display:'none'});

}

$('.mobileMenuToggle a').on('click', function() {

    if($(this).hasClass('open')) {

        $('ul.mobile-navigation').slideUp(400,'easeInOutQuint');

        $(this).removeClass('open');

    } else {

        $('ul.mobile-navigation').slideDown(400,'easeInOutQuint');

        $(this).addClass('open');

    }

    return false;

});
$(function() {
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        if (jQuery('.mobileMenuToggle').is(':visible')) { jQuery('.mobileMenuToggle a').click() }
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

If you want to update the page upon resize, then you should attach resize event and track the visibility in there..

Comment: doesn't seem to work! i added your above code just after 
            $(this).addClass('open');

    }

    return false;

});

Comment: I've updated the code, added full code just in case you missed the spot.. and I've wrapped that line in document ready to assure that html has been rendered already.

Comment: i added as you mentioned above, code is still in site, check your self, not working ? still menu is default closed

Comment: Sorry there was missing closing bracelet there, I've also updated the selector so now it should be bulletproof.

Comment: can you tell also how to do on resize as well ? it worked only when in mobile mobile or small size window, but if i load site in full size desktop browser then resize browser, it does not do it, can you add this function as well on code ?

Comment: Great! Thank you so much you are great! 5 Start :) all udthemes member can get help here of mobile menu!